# Updating using FOR-ALL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, procedure

I have follwing piece of code

```
TYPE t_dc IS TABLE OF TEMP_DC%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
o_u_dc t_dc;
n_index_update_dc BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
```

and then at the end of the script i have

```
            IF n_index_update_dc > 0
            THEN
                FORALL dc IN o_u_dc.first..o_u_dc.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                    UPDATE TEMP_DC
                    SET COL1 = o_u_dc(n_index_update_dc).col1
                    WHERE COLPK = o_u_dc(n_index_update_dc).COLPK;
            END IF;
            COMMIT;
```

and I am getting error `116 7   PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL`

I tried looking up online on oracle documentation but i failed to understand what i am missing. any help ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you get the `n_index_update_dc`  from, but the code you should use is:

```
            IF n_index_update_dc > 0 THEN
                FORALL dc IN o_u_dc.first..o_u_dc.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                    UPDATE TEMP_DC
                    SET COL1 = o_u_dc(dc).col1
                    WHERE COLPK = o_u_dc(dc).COLPK;
            END IF;
            COMMIT;
```

It also depends of how you fill up `o_u_dc`. Maybe that's just not what you want to achieve.